# 3D viewing of a cube placed inside another one

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have a cube in which I have something as a anomaly, consider it as a cube of zeros and I put a smaller cube of numbers in it using the following code:

```
anomaly = zeros(100,100,100);

for j = 40:60
    for jj = 40:60
        for jjj=40:60
            anomaly(j,jj,jjj)=10;
        end
    end
end
```

I want to somehow view it in a 3D figure, for which I can see the anomaly it it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Go for `isosurface`. With isosurface you will be able to extract the inclusion. If you also want to show the whole box, I recommend you to do the following: Create a small box (so it has few faces when converted to isosurface) and then scale it to the real size of the box. You can see this in the following code:

```
anomaly = zeros(100,100,100);               % The anomaly
an2=zeros(100/10+2,100/10+2,100/10+2);      % For plotting pourposes
an2(2:10,2:10,2:10)=1;                      % Create a 10x10x10 box
for j = 40:60
  for jj = 40:60
    for jjj=40:60
      anomaly(j,jj,jjj)=10;
    end
  end
end
iso=isosurface(anomaly,5);                  % Extract surface of inclusion
iso2=isosurface(an2,0.5);                   % create a box
iso2.vertices=(iso2.vertices-1)*10;         % offset( so its in 1-10 range)
                                            % and scaling to be 100x100x100
patch(iso,'facecolor','r','edgecolor','none')
patch(iso2,'facecolor','none');
% this last ones are for having a nicer plot
camlight
axis off
axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: Can the surface be transparent? I want to see the inner inclusion.

Comment: @sabaaa Thats teh inner inclusion actually. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: @sabaaa Great! then could you please accept the answer as valid? is the green arrow below the number in my answer. So future programers can know how to do it!